# Bootstrap email form not working properly. Is it my html or php?

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, email

Is there anything wrong with either my php or my html for my email form? Every time I submit the form online I get a blank page. I'm not sure what else I would have to change since it seems to make sense but I don't know very much about php.

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
    <fieldset>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Name</label>  
       <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email</label>  
       <input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="Phone">Phone</label>  
        <input id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
</section>
</div> <!-- end col-md-4 -->

<div class="col-md-4 message-form">
    <section class="wow zoomInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="0.2s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s; animation-delay: 0.2s;">
        <!-- Textarea -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Message">Message</label>

            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Submit"></label>
            <button id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php
if ($_POST["Submit"]) {
    $textinput = $_POST['textinput'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
    $Message = $_POST['Message'];
    $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'max.henry.campos@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

    $body = "From: $textinput\n E-Mail: $Email\n Message:\n $Message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['textinput']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['Email'] || !filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['Message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errtextinput && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will be in touch</div>';
} else {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page to catch errors?

Comment: What is yout current file name?

Comment: I added that to the top and it does nothing. I'm sure I did something wrong. All of my code relating to my form is posted. I just need to know what's missing and where do I put it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably get the blank page because you're not actually returning anything to the browser. You're just setting $result, not outputting it.

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will be in touch</div>';
} else {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
}
```

echo $result; // ?

Comment: echo $result; // ? is that suppose to go somewhere? I just need to know what's missing and where do I put it.